# Multiple Dependent Wire getRecords

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service

I'm fetching two custom objects in a LWC. Object A__c is the record page's object and is fetched by its `$recordId`. It has a lookup field which points to object B__c's Id.

```
@track bId;

@wire(getRecord, {
  recordId: "$recordId",
  fields: ['A__c.B__c']
})
setA(result) {
  this.bId = getFieldValue(result.data, 'A__c.B__c');
}

@wire(getRecord, {
  recordId: "$bId",
  fields: ['B__c.Id']
})
setB(result) {
  this.b = result;
}
```

I'm finding that `this.b` is not getting set every time the page loads, although it will most of the time. The timing issue is difficult to debug but I feel as though there may be something fundamentally wrong with this approach.

I've also looked into using the `@salesforce/apex/refreshApex` function but haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't think it was ideal, I resolved this by using an Apex controller to fetch the data, rather than `getRecord`.